# Change 'temperature' in RNN to generate text

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I recently followed a [tutorial](http://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) to make a RNN to generate text:
I copied the python code exactly and sort of understand it as well. 
My model has been trained for 20 epochs and it produces a long repetitive loop of 3 words:

```
"and the wour and the wour and the wour..."
```

I have read in Andrej Kaparthy's [blog](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) that changing the temperature of the RNN changes its confidence:

> Decreasing the temperature from 1 to some lower number (e.g. 0.5) makes the RNN more confident, but also more conservative in its samples.

I want to change this temperature level to reduce the confidence of the RNN in order for it to create new patterns, but as this is my first Machine Learning project I don't know how.

Here is my Python/keras code:

Generating Text File:

```
# Generate Text
import sys
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.utils import np_utils

filename = "king_lear.txt"
raw_text = open(filename).read()
raw_text = raw_text.lower()

chars = sorted(list(set(raw_text)))
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

n_chars = len(raw_text)
n_vocab = len(chars)
print "Total Characters: ", n_chars
print "Total Vocab: ", n_vocab

seq_length = 100
dataX = []
dataY = []
for i in range(0, n_chars - seq_length, 1):
    seq_in = raw_text[i:i + seq_length]
    seq_out = raw_text[i + seq_length]
    dataX.append([char_to_int[char] for char in seq_in])
    dataY.append(char_to_int[seq_out])
n_patterns = len(dataX)
print "Total Patterns: ", n_patterns

X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length, 1))

X = X / float(n_vocab)

y = np_utils.to_categorical(dataY)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

filename = "weights-improvement-08-2.0298-bigger.hdf5"
model.load_weights(filename)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

start = numpy.random.randint(0, len(dataX)-1)
pattern = dataX[start]
print "Seed:"
print "\"", ''.join([int_to_char[value] for value in pattern]), "\""

for i in range(60):
    x = numpy.reshape(pattern, (1, len(pattern), 1))
    x = x / float(n_vocab)
    prediction = model.predict(x, verbose=0)
    index = numpy.argmax(prediction)
    result = int_to_char[index]
    seq_in = [int_to_char[value] for value in pattern]
    sys.stdout.write(result)
    pattern.append(index)
    pattern = pattern[1:len(pattern)]

print "\nDone."
```

Learning File:

```
# Learn Sentences
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.utils import np_utils



filename = "king_lear.txt"
raw_text = open(filename).read()
raw_text = raw_text.lower()

chars = sorted(list(set(raw_text)))
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

n_chars = len(raw_text)
n_vocab = len(chars)
print "Total Characters: ", n_chars
print "Total Vocab: ", n_vocab

seq_length = 100
dataX = []
dataY = []
for i in range(0, n_chars - seq_length, 1):
    seq_in = raw_text[i:i + seq_length]
    seq_out = raw_text[i + seq_length]
    dataX.append([char_to_int[char] for char in seq_in])
    dataY.append(char_to_int[seq_out])
n_patterns = len(dataX)
print "Total Patterns: ", n_patterns

X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length, 1))

X = X / float(n_vocab)

y = np_utils.to_categorical(dataY)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}-bigger.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, batch_size=64, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Please help me to do this. If there is anything wrong with this post, don't hesitate to correct me as it is my first question. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3092) on the Keras GitHub. You can add a Lambda layer before the softmax to divide by the temperature:

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / temp))
```

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function):

> For high temperatures, all actions have nearly the same probability and the lower the temperature, the more expected rewards affect the probability. For a low temperature, the probability of the action with the highest expected reward tends to 1.

Comment: Thx a lot. Do I add this line in the generate_text.py, which generates the output. or in the training code? And also, if I want the temperature to be high, do i use a high value, or a low one as it is divided by???

Comment: In the training code, before the softmax layer. High temperature = high value, low temperature = low value.

Comment: I get this error: `NameError: name 'Lambda' is not defined`. How can I solve this? ====> Update:  Used `tf.keras.layers.Lambda` and it solved the issue.